# Github "deploy keys" configuration

Tags: git, github

I'm practicing with an application, to learn a little rails. The application is based on ruby 1.9.3 with rails 4.0.
From codeschool, I follow a course "Rails for Zombies 2" that uses them.
I will not deny that I am a novice at all this.
I want to hang the git repository. So that when I start to make mistakes and have bugs, people who know more than me, have a quick and easy way to access the files in order to help me to solve the problems.

I have a problem with the "deploy keys":
I do not know how to use them.
I added the server "origin", which is where repositodio up the application,

```
origin  git@github.com:user/Tweets4Zombies.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:user/Tweets4Zombies.git (push)
```

pero el terminal me devuelve este erro cuando escribo lo siguiente:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.131' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I think the problem is because you have not set either the "deploy keys", but it escapes me ...

I think yesterday I developed a "deploy keys" but I forgot where it is and do not remember looking back at the "deploy key" is there a command to re-see the "deploy keys" already generated?

Comment: Your ssh keys are stored in your `~/.ssh` directory. You have to share your public key (it should be the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or something like that) with Github in your profile.

Comment: This really has nothing to do w/Ruby or Rails, and everything to do with GitHub. Go figure, [they have really good documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), all your questions should be answered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the key, which proposes the tutorial on the website of git.
For some strange reason, it did not work yesterday. But this morning the problem was resolved.
Thanks for your answers anyway.